# Create a function in Python that takes in n, a, b and returns the number of positive values raised to the nth power that lie in the range [a, b]

Tags: python-3.x, function

power_ranger(2, 49, 65) ➞ 2

## 2 squares (n^2) lie between 49 and 65, 49 (7^2) and 64 (8^2)

power_ranger(3, 1, 27) ➞ 3

## 3 cubes (n^3) lie between 1 and 27, 1 (1^3), 8 (2^3) and 27 (3^3)

power_ranger(10, 1, 5) ➞ 1

## 1 value raised to the 10th power lies between 1 and 5, 1 (1^10)

My code doesn't seem to work properly for n=3. Have no idea why.

```
def power_ranger(n, a, b):
    count = 0
    for i in range(a, b+1):
        if (i**(1/n))%1 == 0:
            print(i)
            count += 1
    
    return count
```

in: power_ranger(2, 49, 100)
out: 49
64
81
100
4

in: power_ranger(3, 1, 72)
out: 1
8
27
3

in: power_ranger(4, 1, 10000)
out: 1
16
81
256
625
1296
2401
4096
6561
10000
10

Comment: Take a look at what the value of `64**(1/3)` is. Does that value modulo 1 give you zero? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

A drastically more efficient solution for your current `power_ranger` (which is now iterates over **all** range whatever big size that is) is to find *max* value which is when raised to the power of `n` results to `high` boundary (of the range) and *min* value which is when raised to the power of `n` results to `low` boundary. The difference between those gives the number of values that fall into the needed range:

```
def power_ranger(n, low, high):
    max_val = int(high ** (1 / n))
    min_val = round(low ** (1 / n))
    return (max_val + 1) - min_val
```

---

```
print(power_ranger(2, 49, 65))
print(power_ranger(2, 49, 100))
print(power_ranger(3, 1, 72))
print(power_ranger(4, 1, 10_000))
print(power_ranger(5, 100, 500_000))
```

---

```
2
4
4
10
11
```